# Retrieving multiple MAX() values from different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to retrieve multiple MAX() values from different tables in postgresql, like

```
SELECT MAX(t1.id) AS t1max, MAX(t2.price) AS t2price FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
```

The output should look like

```
+-----------------------+
| t1max | t2price | ... |
+-----------------------+
| 100   |   20    | ..  |
```

just one row. The above version works, but it's very slow while adding more tables (I think due to cross join). Is there a fast way to achieve that?

Comment: Are the multiple tables related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join only results, not the whole tables :

```
select t1.t1max, t2.t2max 
from
     (select max(id) t1max from table1) t1,
     (select max(price) t2max from table2) t2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using sub selects:

```
SELECT  (SELECT MAX(t1.id) FROM table1 t1) AS t1max, 
        (SELECT MAX(t2.price) FROM table2 t2) AS t2price
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/406a8/1)**